# Insert a component inside a template declared in data with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm struggling with this requirement so here I'm looking for some help.

We are working with `vue-table-2` and when creating a template we want to add a component inside.

In this case it would not be the traditional way to do it, since the table is created inside the data () in `vue`. Even more important is that I have to iterate the data that I receive from the database, so a for (or v-for) loop is required.

Let me show you the code to be clearer. It is the most I could advance but from there I'm stucked.

HTML:

```
<div class="columns" v-if="datatable">
  <div class="column is-12">
     <i data-v-37cb0b94="" class="btn-export material-icons" @click="newExportXls">description</i>
       <qtable 
         :data="datatable"
         :columns="columns" 
         :heading="heading" 
         icon="icon" 
         tableName="pendingTask" 
         :dates="dates" 
         :templates="tasksTableTemplates" // -> Here you can see the template declared in data()
         :formatDate="$t('QPLongDateTime')" 
         ref="vuetable" 
         :mobile="mobile">
     </qtable>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
data() {
tasksTableTemplates: {
    acciones: (h, row) => <menuContextual>{this.drawMenu(row.id)}</menuContextual>,
  },
}

methods: {
  drawMenu() {
   return (
    <div class="is-flex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label><i class="mdi mdi-dots-horizontal is-contextual"></i></label>
          <ul class="contextual-list" v-for={`(item,index) in ${this.dataMenuContextual}`}>
            <a data-v-155ce996="" class="dropdown-item" click="handleFnCall(item.action, item.url)">
              <b-icon pack="fas" icon="item.icon" size="is-small"></b-icon>
              <span class="">item</span>
            </a>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>);
    // <menuContextual :contextId="1" :contextStatusId="0" @clicked="onClickFn"></menuContextual> => Expected and needed component that isn't working.
},
```

Comment: is this vue-table-2 or is this quasar? `<qtable` makes me suspicious

Comment: As I can see in my dependencies I only have vue-tables-2. Although I've this in my component: ```import qtable from '@/components/shared/Table';``` and this Table component is currently importing this: ```import { Event } from '../../ref/vue-tables-2';```

Comment: I believe that you will have to build your template using render functions. I do not think you will be able to include a component inside the JSX

Comment: What is "inside"? There are [slots](https://www.vuetable.com/guide/special-field.html#field-slot)